# Adding new column in SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: sas, gis

I am trying to get a new column named "Zone" in my dataset. I am coding in SAS enterprise and am relatively new to coding. I keep getting

> ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator

Here is my code:

```
data talkmax.location_data_talkmax;
set talkmax.location_data_talkmax;
if GIS_PROVINCE IS MISSING then Zone = .;
else if GIS_PROVINCE = "GAUTENG" then Zone = 100%;
else if GIS_PROVINCE = "FREE STATE" then Zone = "100%";
run;
```

I did try to remove the = sign and replace it with GE. If someone can assist me with this problem I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You should mention what language you are programming in, and any other relevant information (compiler version? GIS provider? other libraries that you are using?). Tagging "math" and "operator" is overly general: all programming languages have those.

Comment: Sorry I am coding in SAS Enterprise Guide

Answer (score 2):

The `Zone` assignment is mixed, should it be the character variable with value "100%" or a numeric variable with value 1.00, and formatted as `PERCENT.`

**I'll presume numeric**

`IS MISSING` is an operator that is only applicable when part of a `WHERE` expression.

Use the `MISSING()` function to detect a missing value as part of an `IF` expression.

```
if missing(GIS_PROVINCE) then Zone = .;
else if GIS_PROVINCE = "GAUTENG" then Zone = 1; /* 100% is not numeric expression */
else if GIS_PROVINCE = "FREE STATE" then Zone = 1;  /* changed to number */

format zone PERCENT.;
```

As a point of mention, a pattern of `IF/THEN/ELSE` around a common variable can become clearer if rewritten as a `SELECT` statement.  It's also easier to spot typos.

```
   select (GIS_PROVINCE);
     when ('GAUTENG'   ) then Zone = 1;
     when ('FREE STATE') then Zone = 1;
     when (' '         ) then Zone = .;
     otherwise /* Hands off my zones */ ;
   end;
```

A patterned mapping over a set of values can also be performed by using a custom format or custom informat.  I'll leave that for another rainy day.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It did work when I used the missing function and when I changed the format.